# Change properties (details) of an exe file

Tags: wix, exe

I have created an exe from msi using WIX.

Now the problem is the resultant exe file takes up properties/details of WIX.

How can I change the properties/details of the newly created exe file. Is it possible to change it using C#?

[image: Error]

Can anyone help me out.